# line-height for centering icon affects outer div in responsive input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I try to make a responsive loginform.
In this i want to make the input and the icon next to it stay side by side und vertical centered.

I came so far that they stick together when the new-line-break hits.

problem:

When I try to make the icon vertical aligned by assigning `line-height: 50px` to the i-element, which is the same height as the outer div has, the outer div gets stretched to 55px. And I don't know why.

If I change the `line-height` to 40px the gap disappears but the icon is not really vertical centered.

I don't see why this is happening. Is it something with the fontawesome?

Because when I assign a very small `font-size` to the icon the misplacement is also disappearing.

Any help appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span6">
    <div class="input-wrap">
        <div class="left">
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="login-icon" style="border: 1px solid red;">
            <div class="login-icon-inner" style="border: 1px solid green;">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
<div class="span6">
    <div class="input-wrap">
        <div class="left">
            <input type="password" />
        </div>
        <div class="login-icon">
            <div class="login-icon-inner">
                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.input-wrap {
 display:              table;
 padding:              0;
}
.left {    
 display:              table-cell;
 width:                100%;
 height:               50px;
}
.left > input {
 width:                100%;
 height:               50px;
 box-sizing:           border-box;
 border-radius:        0;
 margin:               0;
}
.login-icon {
 display:              table-cell;
 height:               50px;
}
.login-icon-inner {
 width:                50px;
 height:               50px;
 text-align:           center;
 background-color:     rgba(230,230,230,1);
}
.span6 {
 margin-top:           5px;
}
body {
 background-color:     rgba(250,250,250,1);
}
i.fa {
 font-size:            24px;
 line-height:          50px;
 margin:               0;
 vertical-align:       baseline;
}
```

Fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/termnml/e9ypqy5t/2/)

Comment: setting `line-height: 40px;`  centers it

Comment: OOPs maioman has the right answer, sorry bud, didn't see that you posted this.

Comment: The aim is to set the icon vertical aligned.
I had this too. But that isn't the solution to my question.

Comment: @termnml you should then, fix the first issue. updated your question then ask specifically what you want. as it sit's right now it is unclear in your question what it is you want.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith
Okay thx. I have edited the question. Hope it is clear enough now.

Comment: @termnml see down votes are not a bad thing, they give motivation for change, you question is now clear so I changed it to an upvote :)

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Indeed understood it when I was writing it again. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found my mistake. There was just a missing `vertical-align: top` missing for the class `.left`. Blindfolded to max :D.